Some details when writing your own loss function in pytorch
When I write my own loss function code, I need to calculate the loss value for each pixel of the tensor data type image, and then add all the loss values ​​to calculate the average.But when I run the code, it shows an error like this:
element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Therefore, I would like to ask, if you want to write the code of the loss function yourself, is it not possible to use the method of calculating the loss value for individual pixels separately?
Any help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Please provide the code that lead to this error.

I would say that the main requirement for the custom loss function is that it has to differentiable, so the autograd can propagate error through it.
The best way of it is to inherit from torch's nn.Module and make sure that you don't break the computational graph, for example:
class MyLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, reduction="mean"):
        super().__init__()
        self.reduction = reduction

    def forward(self, input, target):
        # Some dummy loss:
        loss = target - input

        # Return mean value of the whole batch:
        if self.reduction == "mean":
            return loss.mean()
        else:
            # Otherwise return raw (no reduction) loss values:
            return loss

I don't know what kind of loss you are trying to implement, but the error basically tells you that some of the tensors used in loss computing has requires_grad=False so autograd doesn't know how to compute grads for that particular tensor.
